# Summary row on advanced table

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql table looks like:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
create table ad(
  ad_id int,
  ad_name varchar(10)
);

create table ad_insight(
   id int,
   ad_id int,
   date date, 
   clicks int
 );
create table product(
    product_id int,
    product_name varchar(10)
);
create table product_insight(
    id int,
    product_id int, 
    sale int, 
    date date
);
create table ads_products(
    ad_id int,
    product_id int
);                              
                                    
insert into ad(ad_id, ad_name) values
  (1,'ad1'),
  (2,'ad2'),
  (3,'ad3');
 
 
insert into ad_insight(id, ad_id, date, clicks) values
    (1, 1, '2021-04-25', 1),
    (2, 1, '2021-04-24', 4),
    (3, 1, '2021-04-23', 2),
    (4, 2, '2021-04-25', 6),
    (5, 2, '2021-03-03', 7);


insert into product(product_id, product_name) values
    (1,'prod1'),
    (2,'prod2'),
    (3,'prod3'),
    (4,'prod4'),
    (5,'prod5');
insert into ads_products (ad_id, product_id) values 
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 1); 
insert into product_insight(id, product_id, sale, date) values
    (1, 1, 12, '2021-04-25'),
    (2, 1, 11, '2021-04-24'),
    (3, 1, 13, '2021-04-23'),
    (4, 1, 14, '2021-04-22'),
    (5, 1, 17, '2021-04-21'),
    (6, 1, 15, '2021-04-20'),
    (7, 1, 13, '2021-04-19'),
    (8, 2, 19, '2021-04-25');
```

Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfXrNqQC6wVFYM6NTNX7oJ/6)

A quick explanation of schema:
I have ads:

1. each ad has insights, which tell us when a certain ad was active.
2. each ad has products(many2many - `ads_products` table). Each product has product_insight which tells us how many sales that product generated on a certain day.

To get the following table which will sum up clicks from `ad_insight` table and sum up product_sale from `product_insight` in `2021-04-23` to `2021-04-25` inclusive.

```
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ad_name  | clicks | product_sale |   products   |
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ad1      |      7 |           55 | prod1, prod2 |
| ad2      |      6 |            0 | prod3, prod4 |
| ad3      |      0 |           36 | prod1        |
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

This table is solved by this query:

```sql
SELECT ad.ad_name, IFNULL(clicks, 0) AS clicks, IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_name), '') AS products
FROM ad
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(clicks) AS clicks
    FROM ad_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN product_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN ads_products AS ap ON ap.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON ap.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY ad.ad_id;
```

But now I would like to have a summary row which will look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
| total_ads | total_clicks | distinct_total_product_sale | disctinct_all_products  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
|         3 |           13 |                          55 | prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I have tried something like this:

```sql
SELECT count(*), SUM(clicks), SUM(product_sale), IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products), '') FROM 
    (SELECT ad.ad_name, IFNULL(clicks, 0) AS clicks, IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_name), '') AS products
FROM ad
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(clicks) AS clicks
    FROM ad_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN product_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN ads_products AS ap ON ap.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON ap.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY ad.ad_id) AS x;
```

But this query does not work, because it counts sales for `prod1` two timess.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry I dont understand, what you are talking about.

Comment: Do not change `only_full_group_by`!  It is your friend!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know, in real application i do not have it. Do you know how to solve the question?

Comment: Which value do you expect from your final query in field `distinct_total_product_sale` if value of field `products` for `ad3` wuold be `"prod1, prod5"`?

Comment: @x123chriss . . . Probably even more your friend when developing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first SQL query to avoid changing `@@sql_mode` should be like this:

```
SELECT 
    ad.ad_name, 
    IFNULL(clicks, 0) AS clicks, 
    IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, 
    IFNULL(products, '') AS products
FROM ad
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(clicks) AS clicks
    FROM ad_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN product_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_name) AS products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN product AS p ON ap.product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS p ON ad.ad_id = p.ad_id 
WHERE clicks > 0;
```

The summary row is calculated in the same way, but without grouping in subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    total_ads, 
    p.all_products,
    ai.total_clicks, 
    pi.total_product_sale
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(clicks) AS total_clicks
    FROM ad_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25' AND clicks>0
) AS ai 
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(sale) AS total_product_sale
    FROM product_insight AS pi 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
        AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM ad_insight ai 
          JOIN ads_products AS ap ON ap.ad_id = ai.ad_id
          WHERE ap.product_id = pi.product_id AND ai.clicks > 0 AND
                date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
        )
) AS pi 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT ad_id) AS total_ads, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_name) AS all_products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN product AS p ON ap.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM ad_insight ai 
      WHERE ap.ad_id = ai.ad_id AND ai.clicks > 0 AND
            date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    )
) AS p
```

The problem was that you were trying to join different datasets (clicks and sales), which resulted in redundant rows in the aggregation.

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQns3thV58fGnDB2bRsCNa/5)

Comment: I think you have to optimize this second query for a summary row, because it is executing too long. You are selecting some tables two times.

Comment: Not sure about the `products` column. I added new ad 4 and product 6 with no clicks and no sales and it comes out in your result [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfXrNqQC6wVFYM6NTNX7oJ/9). Is it just all the products for each ad?

Comment: And there was a mistake in my answer. There is no `ad_id column` in the `product_insight` table. I modified the answer and added an example with `ad 4` and `product 6` to the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQns3thV58fGnDB2bRsCNa/1).

Comment: This [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfXrNqQC6wVFYM6NTNX7oJ/9) is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I complicated the solution. Then the solution is simpler without the EXISTS conditions. Check this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQns3thV58fGnDB2bRsCNa/2).

Comment: I have one more question, how to count ads only if clicks>0? Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQns3thV58fGnDB2bRsCNa/3) as you can see first table shows only ads which have clicks>0

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQns3thV58fGnDB2bRsCNa/4)

Comment: But `total_product_sale` should also count ONLY if clicks>0, may you change the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231772/discussion-between-x123chriss-and-user14717238).